# Referencing a dll project with separated binary folder in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, dll, visual-studio-2013

I have a Visual Studio 2013 c++ solution that has two projects:

- one that generates a dll,
- and another that tests this dll.

For each project I modified the output and the intermediate directory.

Solution:

- Project DLL:
- - /bin
- - /build
- - /src
- Project Test:
- - /bin
- - /build
- - /src

Is there any way in which I can reference the generated dll in the test project  without being copied? Something like a static library, which in the case of Visual Studio is just add as a reference that is already linked.

The part that the Visual Studio gets lost is when I changed the binary output folders. With the default option (a folder that generates the binary for all projects) there is no problem.

Answer (score 0):

Edit your test project properties, on Linker>General tab you will find Additional Library Directories setting - add your library directory there. Then you can add your library to Linker>Input>Additional Dependencies.

Comment: This (Linker>Input>Additional Dependencies) only works for static libraries.

Comment: My mistake. In this case you can either compile your project as static library by changing its settings in General Tab, or add the path to the dll to the PATH environment variable.

Comment: Please be aware that when using static (.lib) library you still need to add its directory to Additional Library Directories and the yourlibrary.lib file to Linker>Input>Additional Dependencies. Also you need to provide header files in the Additional Include Directories (C++ General Tab). I just tested this (VS Community 2017) and it works just fine.

Comment: Ok, when I'm using a .DLL I still need to include the .LIB to the compiler, but I couldn't make the visual studio find my .DLL (that is in another directory). I'm already include the headers.